# The company I work lacks vision and innovation. Can I offered it to them or is a lost cause?

Tags: career-development, project-management, career-switch, education

```
I will you give you a bit of background about the situation.
```

I live in a bankrupt country in Europe with big unemployment on youth, and no sight of recovery any time soon. I am 20+ with an unfinished diploma because of financial reasons. Despite that, I manage to get a job as IT developer on one of my country's biggest and richest corporations for a minimum wage.

The first year, I felt grateful to be hired and trusted and I worked really hard to repay it. 
I went to a ton of seminars, earned certifications from online courses and I constantly read books that range from IT to marketing and business management in order to increase the value of my work and do a lot more than just coding.

That effort didn’t go unnoticed by my supervisor and CEOs which have given me a Junior-level Developer wage and giving me primary role to their next year’s plan and a voice to the company’s big meetings.

Despise that, I feel unmotivated to do any serious work.

The reason is the fact that a lot of important positions that decide what will be done and how, are held by people that are impressed with my self-taught work. The work they do is truly amateurish and a lot of times they call to find who made the X product or who made the X report and ask their congratulations to be passed on to me. I am still making baby steps in the industry, It’s a really wrong sign when a 20+ year old creates more outstanding work that employees with degrees and years of experience.

Next year’s plan has given me a primary role but not one that will decide the vision and innovation of our products. My supervisor hears me all the time and has implemented many features that I have suggested. He values me as part of the team and has made it clear that next year’s plan will really heavily on my input and work. But if I don’t have a project leader position and that means I will give ideas that may or may not pass.

I have vision and clear view of how to increase the market value of our products but with the current underperforming manager that seem to be out of loop with the current market, (one of our CEOs) it’s not clear to me how I will be able to convince them about my ideas. They are not going to simply had me over the project management and follow me blindly.

So I feel I have two possible scenarios in front of me.

1. Stay and try to climb the hierarchy. 
   If I am already seen as an impressive employee, maybe I could try and get a project manager position. But because they are many office politics this may wouldn’t work and I will lose time, energy and other opportunities. This could also lead to me giving them my ideas to earn nothing back.
2. Take the risk and leave for another company.
   I feel that I am too young to lead. I should focus on finding a company that has thing to teach me, not the other way around. But I feel held back by my lack of degree, my few years of experience and bad economy. It would be a great risk for me personally. Also I will have to go through the process of impressing people again. People now, already have a good opinion of me.

Out of your personally experience, do you think that as an degree-less employee I could climb the ladder and give the company the vision and innovation, or I should try to move to another company that has more things to teach me?

Comment: I appreciate the comment, Joe. I will think how to re-phrase the question and slim it down.

Comment: Wouldn't be Greece would it?

Answer (score 3):

1. I will simply point out that everywhere you go, you cannot do anything management-wise except through other people including other people who may not share your vision. The only time you get to make your own decisions without having to consult anyone is when you run your own startup. And even then, making decisions without consulting anyone is usually not the greatest idea.
2. Your current employer is smart enough to recognize your merits, your talent, your drive to learn and your willingness to stick your neck out and apply what you learned - not every employer will do that. From your narrative, I infer that your promotions are probably a matter of time. How much time you are willing to give your employer, that's a question for which only you can answer.
3. The bigger your idea(s), the more people you will have to work with management-wise to make your idea(s) happen. And of course, the more people you have to work with, the more time and effort it takes for your ideas to become reality.
4. No one at your employer follows you blindly. That's a positive not a negative. It forces you to run sanity checks on yourself and soundness checks on your ideas. And speaking for myself, those who follow me blindly scare the shit out of me - I feel much safer when I am questioned and challenged and I answer the tough questions head-on and put the hard challenges down. The tough questions that I fear are the tough questions that make sense and the hard challenges that I fear are those that are rational, smart and real world based. I believe in getting vaccinated, I don't believe in never getting sick.

Regardless of whether you decide to stay or to leave, give your current employer's people a break. Your lack of the wrong kind of experience, your level of education and your outside-the-box ideas are a draft of fresh air to them. They are probably trying to breathe that draft of fresh air without also catching a cold.

Answer (score 1):

As a junior developer, you aren't going to dictate the direction of a large company's future products, however good you think you are (or however good *they* think you are).  That's the job of marketing and senior management.

You could stick around, and work your way up to management, but that will take years.  Switching to another company won't really change anything, unless it's a very small company, where you will have direct contact with whoever makes the decisions.

The alternative would be to start your own company - if you think you're up to it.